# How to safely chain methods?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is there a way to "safely" chain methods in PHP and simply return `null` if some previous method returns `null`? Otherwise, an error would be thrown: `trying to get property on non-object`;

For example, the following code checks whether a customer's phone number has changed using a QuickBooks SDK.  I don't have control over these methods.

`$customer->getPrimaryPhone()` will always return an object since the form wouldn't have been submitted otherwise, but `$old->getPrimaryPhone()` may return `null` if no phone number existed previously.

The following is required to get the phone number:

`$old->getPrimaryPhone()->getFreeFormNumber()`

If `getPrimaryPhone()` returns null, then an error would be thrown.

My question is: **How would I avoid code repition in the following case?**

```
if (!empty($old->getPrimaryPhone())) {
    if ($customer->getPrimaryPhone()->getFreeFormNumber() !== $old->getPrimaryPhone()->getFreeFormNumber()) {
        // Repetive code here
    }   
} else {
        // Repetive code here
}
```

Comment: `if ($oldPrimaryPhone = $old->getPrimaryPhone()) ... !== $oldPrimaryPhone->getFreeFormNumber()`

Comment: Even though those methods have the same name, and even if both objects have the same value for `getFreeFormNumber()`, sometimes the property is stored in an array at index 0, and sometimes is stored as a primitive value.  Therefore, I can't compare the higher level objects.  Again, not in my control.

Comment: Depending on the practical chain combinations, returning a NullObject sometimes makes sense.

Comment: @mario, Exactly.  I would like to find a way to get `$old->getPrimaryPhone()->getFreeFormNumber()` to return null, or an empty object rather than throw an error `trying to get property on non object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be inclined to implement an `equals` method on your `PhoneNumber` class (or whatever it's called). For example

```
public function equals(PhoneNumber $otherNumber) {
    return $otherNumber !== null && $this->getFreeFormNumber() === $otherNumber->getFreeFormNumber();
}
```

Then you can simply use

```
if (!$customer->getPrimaryPhone()->equals($old->getPrimaryPhone())
```

---

If you've got other logic that needs to be applied (as indicated in your comment about arrays), you can easily implement that in the `equals` method.

Comment: Interesting.  I have several fields with this problem.  I could of course create a method for each field, but is there a generic way to do this without knowing the second level method names?  If so, I can use only one function to compare other fields like `address`, `email`, etc.

Comment: You could have all your *field* classes with the `equals` method implement then just call `return $this->field->equals($other->field) &&..` in the parent class `equals` method